# How to connect a router in Aiogram 3.x.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

I have a working bot code that responds to the /start command with the greeting "Hello, world!"

Aiogram version is 3.3.0

`main.py`

```
import asyncio

from aiogram import Dispatcher
from aiogram.fsm.storage.memory import MemoryStorage

from bot_instance import bot
from handlers import common


async def main():
    dp = Dispatcher()

    dp.include_router(common.router)

    await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

`bot_instance.py`

```
from aiogram import Bot


bot = Bot(
    token="123abc",
    parse_mode="HTML"
)
```

`handlers/common.py`

```
from aiogram import Router
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart
from aiogram.types import Message


router = Router()

@router.message(CommandStart())
async def cmd_start(message: Message):
    await message.answer("Hello, world!")
```

But I want to register the function `cmd_start()` not through the decorator, but with the function.

Updated `handlers/common.py`

```
from aiogram import Router
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart
from aiogram.types import Message


router = Router()

async def cmd_start(message: Message):
    await message.answer("Hello, world!")

def register_handers_common(router: Router):
    router.message.register(cmd_start(CommandStart()))
```

How do I connect the router to the dispatcher now?
What the main.py page should look like now?

I found a solution for aiogram 2.x.x, but in the third version routers appeared and the solution became non-trivial for me.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to call method `register_handers_common()` and change register to `router.message.register(cmd_start, CommandStart())` [(method)](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/1281bf551afae80eb549f80bdadc0c77a0a2d20a/aiogram/dispatcher/event/telegram.py#L57)

file `handlers/common.py`

```
from aiogram import Router
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart
from aiogram.types import Message


router = Router()

async def cmd_start(message: Message):
    await message.answer("Hello, world!")

def register_handers_common(router: Router):
    router.message.register(cmd_start, CommandStart())

register_handers_common(router)
```